# Horizontal centering of PayPal buttons whose width is specified as percentage

Tags: css, reactjs, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Please have a look at [this playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-playground-forked-t3qz32), which presents the following React code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  PayPalScriptProvider,
  PayPalButtons,
  usePayPalScriptReducer
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="hv-center-container">
      <div>
        <div className="thank-you h-center-container">
          <div>Make the viewport as wide as you can, and some more</div>
        </div>
        <div className="h-center-container">
          <PayPalScriptProvider>
            <div className="paypal">
              <PayPalButtons
                style={{
                  layout: "vertical",
                  shape: "pill",
                  tagline: false,
                  height: 55
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </PayPalScriptProvider>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

and the styles:

```css
.hv-center-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.h-center-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.thank-you {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.paypal {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Had I specified the `width` property of the `.paypal` rule in pixels, the PayPal buttons would center properly. But now that it's in percentage, they don't.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: The buttons have a max-width that can be less than 100% of your `.paypal` container. The container is centered but the buttons have default alignment within the container.

Comment: @TimR So what workaround is there? I can't believe PayPal made it impossible to design pleasantly looking pages with their buttons on them... Also, I remember reading that by default the buttons occupy the whole surrounding element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal uses `@media` queries to declare `min-width` and `max-width`. The widest the buttons can get is 750px. When your `.paypal` container is wider than that, the buttons become left-aligned inside of the wider `.paypal` container.

To have the `.paypal` container match the width of the buttons inside the `<iframe>`, you can use the same `@media` queries that PayPal uses.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 75px) {
  .paypal {
    min-width: 75px;
    max-width: 150px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) {
  .paypal {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 200px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  .paypal {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 300px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  .paypal {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .paypal {
    min-width: 500px;
    max-width: 750px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do they become centered when I specify the width in pixels, but not in percentage?

Comment: The buttons appear to be 100% wide up to 750px, so will be centered if you specify a width less than that. I've reworded my answer for clarity.